# NativeModules.RNNotificationActions is null after linking

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

```
import {NativeModules, NativeAppEventEmitter} from 'react-native';
console.log("Hello NATIVE" + NativeModules.RNNotificationActions);
```

---this is null

I'm using `react-native-ios-notification-actions`, a popular library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kingstinct/react-native-ios-notification-actions

I have RCTPushNotifications xcode project in my Libraries folder.
I have the libRCTPushNotification linked.

I re ran `react-native link`.

I implement in AppDelegate.m

```
// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

but always RNNotificationActions is null. Why?

Comment: `import NotificationActions from 'react-native-ios-notification-actions'`

Comment: That code is within that module

Comment: It's a file that was written to define it. It says to use it like this.